# Get iterable Tensor without running eval

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Is there a way to make a Tensor iterable without running `eval()` to get its numpy array?

I am trying to iterate through two parts of a tensor after using `split()` on it, but it happens within the construction of the hidden layers of my neural network, so it needs to happen before I am able to start a session.

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, nbits])
layer = [x]
for i in range(1,numbits):
    layer.append(tf.add(tf.matmul(weights[i-1], layer[i-1]), biases[i-1]))
    aes, bes = tf.split(1, 2, layer[-1])
        if i%2 == 1:
            for am, a, b in zip(add_layer, aes, bes):
                layer.append(am.ex(a, b))
```

The problem is that `layer[-1]` is a `tf.placeholder` at this point, so `aes` and `bes` are both tensors, and I can't iterate through them with `zip()`.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: @Peter Hawkins, thank you.  I was afraid that there wouldn't be an easier way than digging into the Tensorflow builtins.  What I ended up doing was using `tf.slice()` to get each split into its individual elements, which was less painful than I was expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't; not directly.

It's easiest to think about Tensorflow programs as being split into two phases: a building Python phase that builds a computation graph, and a execution phase that runs the computation graph. Nothing actually runs during the building phase; all computation happens during the execution phase. The building phase can't depend on the results of the execution phase, except by running the graph (`session.run()`, `.eval()`, etc.)

You can't iterate over a Tensor while building the graph, because it doesn't actually get evaluated to a specific set of values until you call `session.run()`. Instead it's just a reference to a node in the computation graph.

In general, you have to use Tensorflow functions to manipulate Tensors, not Python primitives (like zip). One way I like to think of it is that it's almost like a Tensor is a radioactive object in a sealed box, and you can only handle it indirectly using a robot that can perform a certain set of actions (Tensorflow library functions) :-) So you likely need to find a way to express your task using Tensorflow primitives.

If you gave a complete example of what you're trying to do, it might be possible to say more (it's not clear to me from your code fragment). One possibility might be to use `tf.split` to split the tensors up into Python lists of subtensors, and then use something like zip on the lists.

I hope that helps!